# installing linux on a mac

Tags: linux, macos, boot-camp

i have mac pro and i wanted to install debian on it but i guess i have problem now.

i have windows 7 installed on bootcamp partition, before i started installing linux, i created a partition size of 75 gb then i restarted mac and boot it from debian dvd. then i divided that 75 gb to 2 partitions, one is 600 mb freespace other is ext3 formatted.

i installed debian (but it just used 1 dvd even though i got 5 dvd downloaded) then mac restarted.

but now i cannot even see windows on bootlist. it just let me boot in mac os x now. how can i fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use something like [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) to triple boot.

Comment: i installed it now, but nothing happens on startup, i cant start windows or linux, just mac os starts

Comment: If there is nothing of value on the Windows partition, it'd be best to  wipe that and start over..This link nay help :

http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2010/05/how-to-triple-boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-boot-camp-required/

Answer (score 0):

Give VMWare Fusion 3 a try.  Although Debian is not formally supported, this article explains how to set it up.

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/211821